# My JQuery code is not working in Internet Explorer while working on other Browser like Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

**In this code the JQuery code is not working in Internet Explorer while it works on Firefox and Chrome

`//alert($('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val());`
 this alert is not show here why?**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .a {
            color: red
        }
        .b {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .c {
            font-size: 55px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">this is my div
        <input type="text" value="50" name="first_input">first label</input>
        <button>first button</button>
        <input type="text">second label</input>
        <input type="text">third label</input>
        <input type="text">fourth label</input>
        <button>second button</button>
        <input type="text">fifth label</input>
        <button>third button</button>
        <input type="text">sixth label</input>
        <button>fourth button</button>
        <input type="text">seventh label</input>
        <button>fifth button</button>
        <button>sixth button</button>
        <button id="ss">seventh button</button>
        <label id="lbl1">hello</label>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:text').eq(0).attr({
                title: 'please input the value',
                placeholder: 'insert a value',
                name: 'input_type',
                //value:25
            });
            $('#ss').click(function () {
                <!--  alert($('input[type="text"]').get(0).value);  this is not work on I.Explorer  -->
                <!--   alert($('input[type="text"]').get(0).name);  this is not work on I.Explorer  -->
                <!--   alert($('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val());    -->
                alert($('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val()); <!-- this is not work on I.Explorer  -->
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `name:'input_type',` <- try removing the comma

Comment: please go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and make a small fiddle and post it here, so we can help you :)

Comment: @DanielCheung There's enough code above to not require a jsfiddle.  People are too quick to ask for that.

Comment: @SalmanA hit the nail on the head.  You can get away with a trailing comma in object constructors in most browsers, but not IE.  It falls over, stopping all code execution afterwards.

Comment: Solution **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2413352/1906094)** says _use short closing tags_  which means instead of `<input>..</input>` use `<input .../>`

Comment: First of all placeholder wil not work with IE untill you use external script for that. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:text').eq(0).attr({
                title: 'please input the value',
                placeholder: 'insert a value',
                name: 'input_type', <- ERROR HERE
                //value:25
            });
```

Dont add comma(,) to the last property. IE does not support this.
So remove that comma and try I think It will work properly.. All the best.

Change your Input syntax also.

Proper syntax is: `<input *attributelist*    />`

eg

```
 <input type="text" value="50" name="first_input" />
```

-its a good code habit.

**UPDATED**

```
<div id="container">this is my div
    <input type="text" value="50" name="first_input" />
        <button>first button</button>
        <input type="text" />second label
        <input type="text" />third label
        <input type="text" />fourth label
        <button>second button</button>
        <input type="text" />fifth label
        <button>third button</button>
        <input type="text" />sixth label
        <button>fourth button</button>
        <input type="text" />seventh label
        <button>fifth button</button>
        <button>sixth button</button>
        <button id="ss">seventh button</button>
        <label id="lbl1">hello</label>
    </div>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:text').eq(0).attr({
                    title: 'please input the value',
                    placeholder: 'insert a value',
                    name: 'input_type',
                    value:25
                });
    $('#ss').click(function () {
                   alert($('input[type="text"]').get(0).value);  
                });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xETvv/)